# How to get an alert from macOS when an app uses more than certain amount of RAM?

Tags: bash, macos, memory, cron

Trying to prevent some.. stack overflow . I have memory leaks in my programs and they end up using 128GB of RAM.

Is there any program that would give me an alert after RAM exceeds an amount of my choice?

Or should I program it myself? Some cron job?
If so, any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: Are you sure they're using 128 GB of real memory, and not that they merely had 128 GB of virtual memory space assigned?

Comment: I have 64GB of physical RAM, and it was writing swap memory for over 60GB. My Activity memory indicated 128GB of memory used

Comment: Yep, that's real memory use, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `cron` job plus some formatting of `vm_stat` or `sysctl` can do this - see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/197059/mac-os-x-sysctl-get-total-and-free-memory-size).

You could do the alert with some AppleScript too:

```sh
osascript -e 'display notification "This device's memory usage has exceeded 128GB!" with title "Memory Usage Warning!"'
```

However, I find solving the problem itself usually works best (e.g. fixing the memory leak :P)